# Array needs a constant value

Tags: c++

I am creating a program that counts the vowels and the consonant
I am trying to convert the string to an array so I could evaluate each character as an element

but this part of the code

> char chray[chartotal + 1];

throws an error that says,
"expression must have a constant value"

is there a way to fix this or do it in a simpler way?

*sorry for the large space I was gonna put the code that evaluates the number of vowels there.*

```
string io; 
string input ="";

//text processing
        //removing spaces.
        cout << "Please enter your string:" << endl;
        getline(cin, input);
        int charnum=input.length();
        chartotal = input.length();//total characters w/ spaces

        char chray[chartotal + 1];

        //char num without spaces
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            if (input.at(i) == ' ') {
                charnum--;
            }
        }









noc = charnum - nov;




//final Display
system("CLS");
cout << "Original String is "<< input <<endl;
cout << "The Total number of Characters " << chartotal  << "." << endl;
cout << "The Total number of Characters excluding space is " << charnum <<"."<< endl;
cout << "The Total number of Vowels is " << nov <<"." <<endl;
cout << "The Total number of consonants is " << noc << "." << endl;
```

}

Comment: [Variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) have never been a part of C++. If you want a string use `std::string`, otherwise `std::vector`.

Comment: As an aside, what is the use of `chray`? You attempt to define it but never use it?

Comment: Why are you planning to copy the string you already have into an array?  You can iterate on the string contents (as you already do creating your count of things that aren't spaces), which are already `char` for `std::string`.

Comment: I meant instead of `char[]` at all in this code use a `std::string` for this.

Comment: @Perette i dont need to break it apart into an array to evaluate each character in my string? i was doing it so I could evaluate each part of my string if they are a vowel or not.

Comment: Something like `for (const auto& ch : input) { // do something with ch }` would be a better start right after `getline(cin, input);` no need for the `chray` variable at all. No need to copy the `input` string in any way.

Comment: `for (c : input) { if (is_vowel(c) { ++vowels; } /* etc... */ }`